# how to sum columns based on ifelse condition in r

Tags: r

i'm trying to sum all the columns  with if else condition replaced null values with 999 if not 999 it should add all columns can some one tell  better one, i'm getting wrong value by using this,

like need to add sum of columns and then finally add the sum of all columns

sum((A1a(i)+A2b(i)))

```
sum((ifelse((df$A1a!= 999), df$A1a,0)+
                         ifelse((df$A2b!= 999), df$A2b,0)+
                         ifelse((df$A3c!= 999), df$A3c,0))
```

example:

```
  A B C  D
# 1 4 7 10
# 2 5 8 11
# 1 3 1 1


if B!=1 (4+5+3)
if  C!=1 then add (7+8) for c and 
if D! = 1for (10+11)
finally (12+15+21)=48
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use :

```
cols <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
sum(df[cols] * (df[cols] != 1))

#[1] 50
```

`df != 1` would return `TRUE`/`FALSE` value which is multiplied by `df` so all the 1's are turned to 0 and rest of them are kept as it is.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 2L, 1L), B = c(4L, 5L, 3L), C = c(7L, 
8L, 1L), D = c(10L, 11L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: it's not all columns only specific columns i need to add

Comment: Simply subset the columns you need (or remove those you dont need)

Comment: and if i want multiply another column then i need to do this?
```sum(df[cols] * (df[cols] != 1)* (df$y))```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the condition `!=1` to subset and `sum` the result:

```
y <- x[-1]
#y <- x[c("B","C","D")] #Alternativ
sum(y[y!=1])
#[1] 48
```

Data

```
x <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,1), B=c(4,5,3), C=c(7,8,1), D=c(10,11,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to a numeric vector

```
sum(as.matrix(df)[df != 999])
```

There's no need to convert to `999` however so you could do

```
sum(as.matrix(df)[is.na(df)])
```

and keep the na's